# Sort two columns together

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns of which I want two: Country and Happiness Score. I want to get the 10 countries with highest Happiness Score, I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('world_happiness_2016.csv')
df2= df.set_index('Country')
df3=df['Happiness Score']

print df3.copy().sort_values(inplace=True)
```

Returns:

```
None
```

Comment: `inplace=True` operates inplace surprisingly enough and returns `None`, remove this param as the default is `inplace=False` which will return the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you just do

```
df=df.sort_values(['Happiness Score'])
print(df['Country'].tolist()[0:10])
```

Comment: No problem. And memory efficient, too.

Answer (score 0):

`inplace=True` modifies the object in place so it returns `None`, if you remove this param the default is `inplace=False` so it will return the calculated result:

```
print(df3.sort_values())
```

If you had just done

`print(df3)` after your existing code you would find that `df3` had been sorted